# Pitching mlb baseball

Tags: baseball, mlb

Pitcher "A" completes an inning. Pitcher "B" comes in to start the following inning. Question, when is pitcher "A" officially removed from the game, or when does the pitching change officially occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pitching change officially occurs when the new pitcher takes the mound. For example, let's say Pitcher A finishes a half inning with his team losing. During the next half inning, his team takes the lead and the manager either pinch-hits for Pitcher A or decides to put in Pitcher B to pitch next, Pitcher A would still get a Win assuming his team maintains the lead they got.

Comment: To be clear, you mean the team must take the lead before Pitcher A is replaced by a pinch hitter, right?

Comment: @chepner No, that's not a requirement.  Pitcher A can be removed for a pinch hitter at any time (lets say it's even the first batter of the inning), but remains the "pitcher of record" until another pitcher takes the mound.

Comment: OK, I see that's covered by Rule 10.17(a).